# How to database.update the date value

Tags: android, database, time, updating

I have a date value in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss`

So from this line `data = params.getString("data");` i get the date I have set before in another activity.
So with a button click I need to add + 10 minutes to the date value.

I do know its through the `value.put("...",...);` but as I don't want to change the DATE only the TIME of the value. How should do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance of Calendar:

```
 SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");

 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.setTime(currentDate.parse(data)); // your date value
 c.add(Calendar.MINUTE,10);
 newDate = c.getTime()
```

Comment: So on the `value.put` it will be: `value.put("data", newDate);` right?

Comment: Right newDate will be the old date + 10 minutes.  The calendar takes care of cases like 10:55 -> 11:05, but you need to think about what happens if time >23:49:59.  You said you don't want the date to change but "2012-10-18 23:51:00" + 10 minutes = 2012-10-19 00:01:00"

Comment: The app is made to people at my work during work time so 7:30am to 18pm :D and if that happens its also setted something at myservice :D

Comment: the newDate, shouldn't it be: `Date newDate = c.getTime();` ?

Comment: Er, yes, of course.  If you don't already have a field declared for it.

Comment: Alright so now my `.put` says the newDate should be a string or it wont work, any suggestions? convert the date to string?

Comment: I think you can figure out the rest ;)  One tip, dates in SQL updates must be enclosed in single quotes.  Please accept my answer and, if you get stuck with a new problem, start a new question!  Thanks.

Comment: Alright... but the question is related to this and i should accept the answer if i get it right I guess, I just need to know how to `.put` the newDate because it's a Date value and the `.put` says it has to be a String value.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, SO is not designed for line by line problem solving or for extended comments.  Of course it must be String, Google  for how to convert a date to a String!  I could give you a fish and eat today, or you can learn how to fish and eat forever!